# Give all non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 234 and order 72

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

for 72 I know $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} $ is a abelian group but I think it is also isomorphic so how would I find a non-isomorphic abelian group? Thank you for your help.

Comment: What does "isomorphic" mean to you?

Comment: Use Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups.

Comment: Your phrasing is not grammatical, as Theophile alludes to.

Answer (score 1):

$234=2×3^2×13.$
Number of non isomorphic abelian groups of order $234=$P($1$)P($2$)P($1$)$=2$.The two groups are $Z_{234}\;\;,$$Z_6×Z_3×Z_{13}$
Where $P($n$)$=Number of partitions of $n$
This is a direct consequence of the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.
You can do the other part yourself

Comment: so for 72 the number of non-isomorphic abelian groups of order 72=6?

Comment: The product of partitions of the powers of each prime

Comment: I'm confused wouldn't order 72=P(3)P(2)?

Comment: Yes and that is 8

Comment: oh also how did you know $\mathbb{Z}_{6} \times \mathbb{Z}_{3} \times \mathbb{Z}_{13}$ was not isomorphic and not $\mathbb{Z}_{2} \times \mathbb{Z}_{9} \times \mathbb{Z}_{13}$?

Comment: Because gcd $(2,9,13)=1$ and then this again becomes $Z_{234}$.

Comment: I'm so confused isn't gcd$(6,3,13)=1$ so it'll become $\mathbb{Z}_{234}$ also how do you know P(3)P(2)=8?

Comment: @Upstart: It is because they're coprime *in pairs*.